# How to distinguish even/odd date in javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

i am trying to add a class to all odd dates but i do not succeed in it. What i am doing wrong?

```
<ul>  
    <li>2021-06-01</li>  
    <li>2021-06-02</li>  
    <li>2021-06-03</li>  
    <li>2021-06-04</li>  
    <li>2021-06-05</li>  
    <li>2021-06-06</li>  
    <li>2021-06-07</li> 
    <li>2021-06-08</li>  
    <li>2021-06-09</li>  
    <li>2021-06-10</li>  
</ul>
```

And my js:

```
var date = $("li").text();
var lastchar = $("li").text().substr(9, 10); // last char from date
if(lastchar % 2 == 1) { // odd number
    $("li").addClass('odd'); // add class odd to li
}
```

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: How do you expect that `var lastchar = $("li").text().substr(9, 10);` should work. `text()` will return the textual content of the first match element and `$("li").addClass('odd');` will apply `odd` to all `li` elements.

Comment: As a note: You can use a negative index to start at the end:  `'2021-06-01'.substr(-1)` will give you `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter` to filter the elements and then just `addClass` to that.

```js
$("li").filter((i,v) => parseInt($(v).text().substr(9,10),10) % 2 !== 0)
      .addClass("odd");
```

```css
.odd{ background-color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>  
    <li>2021-06-01</li>  
    <li>2021-06-02</li>  
    <li>2021-06-03</li>  
    <li>2021-06-04</li>  
    <li>2021-06-05</li>  
    <li>2021-06-06</li>  
    <li>2021-06-07</li> 
    <li>2021-06-08</li>  
    <li>2021-06-09</li>  
    <li>2021-06-10</li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap your code with `.each()` to loop through all items and implement the logic one by one:

```js
$('li').each(function(_, el){
  var date = $(el).text();
  var lastchar = $(el).text().substr(9, 10); // last char from date
  if(lastchar % 2 == 1) { // odd number
      $(el).addClass('odd'); // add class odd to li
  }
});
```

```css
.odd{
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>  
    <li>2021-06-01</li>  
    <li>2021-06-02</li>  
    <li>2021-06-03</li>  
    <li>2021-06-04</li>  
    <li>2021-06-05</li>  
    <li>2021-06-06</li>  
    <li>2021-06-07</li> 
    <li>2021-06-08</li>  
    <li>2021-06-09</li>  
    <li>2021-06-10</li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
        var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li")
        var connect = []
        for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            connect.push(parseInt(li[i].innerHTML.slice(8, 10)))
        }
        for (var b = 0; b < connect.length; b++) {
            if (connect[b] % 2 != 0) {
                li[b].classList.add("odd")
            } else {
                li[b].classList.add("even")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery, you can use a selector, then iterate over the collection and assign a class to those where the last character is an even number, e.g.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(node => 
    node.textContent.slice(-1) % 2? null : node.classList.add('red')
  )
};
```

```css
.red {color: red}
```

```html
<ul>  
    <li>2021-06-01</li>  
    <li>2021-06-02</li>  
    <li>2021-06-03</li>  
    <li>2021-06-04</li>  
    <li>2021-06-05</li>  
    <li>2021-06-06</li>  
    <li>2021-06-07</li> 
    <li>2021-06-08</li>  
    <li>2021-06-09</li>  
    <li>2021-06-10</li>  
</ul>
```

You might want to throw in *trim* like `node.textContent.trim().slice(-1)` to remove any leading or trailing whitespace that sneaks in.